# How to find the index of an element within nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following lists:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
b = [a[5], a[4], a[3]]
```

If I use `b.index("f")` I get 0. What I want it to output, however, is 5. How can I get the index of "f" in list a through the list b?

Comment: `[a.index(e) for e in b]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because the elements in `a` are strings which don't "know" where they are in the list. Hence when you index them out of the list (e.g. `a[5]`), the strings can't tell you where they came from in the list.

---

I'm not sure what your aim is through creating this new list, but you could just store the indexes of the elements rather than the elements themselves in `b`.

e.g.

```
b = [5, 4, 3]
```

which would allow you to then create a function which would "get the index  of [an element] in list `a` through list `b`:

```
def get_ind_in_a_thru_b(e):
    i = a.index(e)
    if i in b: return i
    else: raise ValueError
```

which works as if there were some magical method to get the index of elements in `b` as if they were in `a`:

```
>>> get_ind_in_a_thru_b('f')
5
>>> get_ind_in_a_thru_b('g')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_ind_in_a_thru_b
ValueError: 'g' is not in list
>>> get_ind_in_a_thru_b('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in get_ind_in_a_thru_b
ValueError
```

*note how even though `'a'` is in the list `a`, since it is not in the list `b`, it is not returned*

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Elements of `b` are resolved to strings and lose all knowledge of their indices in `a`. You can write a small class to store the value *and* index:

```
from operator import attrgetter

a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

class GetItemPos():
    def __init__(self, L, idx):
        self.idx = idx
        self.var = L[idx]

b = [GetItemPos(a, 5), GetItemPos(a, 4), GetItemPos(a, 3)]

indices = list(map(attrgetter('idx'), b))  # [5, 4, 3]
values = list(map(attrgetter('var'), b))   # ['f', 'e', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way, b would be `["f", "e", "d"]` and the indexes of that elements are 0,1,2. You can create b in this way, though:

```
b = [a.index(a[5]), a.index(a[4]), a.index(a[3])]
```

Otherwise, if you want indexes and values you can use a dictionary:

```
b = {a[3]: a.index(a[3]), a[4]: a.index(a[4]),a[3]: a.index(a[3])}
```